# Change UICollectionView Cell height using Pinch Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have images within each of CollectionView cell and I set sizes using `sizeForItem`. And I would like to pinch cell to change it's height. I've tried adding a pinch gesture to the collectionView and getting correct index path for that matter, but invalidating the layout each change event seems to crash the app.. so I'm guessing I should use custom layout.

So I've found this question which seems like something I could use [What method should be used to dynamically change the size of UICollectionViewCell on selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958572/what-method-should-be-used-to-dynamically-change-the-size-of-uicollectionviewcel)

From function `rectFor(index)` I would return frame for each cell. But I can't get current cell frame from

```
self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))?.frame
```

Am I missing something?